# Parsing chess notation string in R to find last move number

Tags: r, chess

Have a list of strings ChessNotation like this:

"26. Qb7 Qc6 0-1"
"31. g3 Rh2 32. a4 Rxh3 33. Kg2 Rh5 34. a5 Rg5 35. Ra8 Rg4 1/2-1/2"
"36. Bd4 Bxb3 37. Rxc7+ Bxc7 38. axb3 a6 39. h3 Ke6 40. g4 1-0"
"34. b4 Ra8 35. Ng5 Rxa3 36. Nf3 Rb3 37. Kg3 Rxb4 38. h4 Kf6 39. Ng1 Kf5 0-1"
"25. Rad1 Qc6 26. Qb8 1-0"

I want to parse out the last move number from each.
So results from above would be: 26, 35, 40, 39, 26

Original plan was to str_split with space and then figure out if I need the 3rd last or the 4th last entry in the resulting list.

Problem is: I can't figure out how to get the length from a vector of string of string. If I do:

length(str_split(ChessNotation,' '))

I get 5, the number of entries in the ChessNotation list. I need to get back a vector with the number of entries in each str_split list.

I'd appreciate any help with getting the length of each list or with how to parse out the move number I need in general.

I should note I have no idea how to do regular expressions, but if anyone can point out how to do them for this instance that would be perfect too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The package `stringr` will be useful to you, especially since you do not already know regular expressions. The vignettes can walk you through a lot of examples.

Here is a solution using `str_extract_all` from that package.

```
library(stringr)
x <- list("26. Qb7 Qc6 0-1",
          "31. g3 Rh2 32. a4 Rxh3 33. Kg2 Rh5 34. a5 Rg5 35. Ra8 Rg4 1/2-1/2",
          "36. Bd4 Bxb3 37. Rxc7+ Bxc7 38. axb3 a6 39. h3 Ke6 40. g4 1-0",
          "34. b4 Ra8 35. Ng5 Rxa3 36. Nf3 Rb3 37. Kg3 Rxb4 38. h4 Kf6 39. Ng1 Kf5 0-1", 
          "25. Rad1 Qc6 26. Qb8 1-0")

extract_func <- function(x) {
  x2 <- unlist(str_extract_all(x, "\\d*\\."))
  as.numeric(x2[length(x2)])
}

unlist(lapply(x, extract_func))

[1] 26 35 40 39 26
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplish method:

```
data = data.frame(x = c("26. Qb7 Qc6 0-1",
                        "31. g3 Rh2 32. a4 Rxh3 33. Kg2 Rh5 34. a5 Rg5 35. Ra8 Rg4 1/2-1/2",
                        "36. Bd4 Bxb3 37. Rxc7+ Bxc7 38. axb3 a6 39. h3 Ke6 40. g4 1-0"))
splits = str_split(data$x, pattern = " ")
last_move = function(x){
  x[max(grep(pattern = "^[0-9]+\\.$", x = x))]
}
data$last_moves = mapply(FUN = last_move, x = splits)
```